# Google Drive status icons not appearing in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, icons, dropbox, cloud-storage, google-drive

I have installed the Google Drive client for Windows.
However, the status icons (green check mark, à la DropBox) are not appearing next to the files' names in Explorer.

I'm running Windows 7 Pro SP1, with Google Drive client Version 1.5.3449.3345.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mine does not display any icons either. Are you sure there will be some icons?

Comment: There are supposed to be checkmarks, yes. Other people are reporting them missing and the Google Drive known issues page is showing that they know about this for the Mac at least.

Comment: Mine aren't displaying, but I wonder if the Carbonite icons are interfering. For what it's worth I'm not seeing icons on my Dropbox files either.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post with a similar problem but other software: [Why are Icon Overlays (from 3rdParty-Apps) not showing up in the Win8 Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/542116/why-are-icon-overlays-from-3rdparty-apps-not-showing-up-in-the-win8-explorer/542222#542222)

It seems that you have two options:

- Delete any entries other than GD (Google Drive)
- Rename the entries (like inserting numbers in front of the name), because Windows takes them by order (0-9; then a-z something like)...  it will looks like this, but with GDrive entries taking the 0's and 1's as the first entries:

[image]