# Why are Icon Overlays (from 3rdParty-Apps) not showing up in the Win8 Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, icons

These wonderful icon overlays that give you useful information in the Windows Explorer are not showing up. [image: a Screenshot of what I mean]

It's the most annoying with Dropbox (I already read https://www.dropbox.com/help/154/en). I just tried reinstalling Dropbox - no help. I have this problem also with the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) so I don't think that it is a dropbox problem specifically; and something is wrong in my OS. The OS is actually a pretty fresh clean-install...

OS: Win8 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically, so that an installation program could notice the problem and fix it during install?

Comment: related but asked later: https://superuser.com/q/809529/3588

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Looks like you've installed too many tools which register Overlay icons. Windows has an ugly [limit of only 15 overlay icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190313-00/?p=101094) because of old 16 Bit code that can't be changed:

> The value 15 came from the corresponding limit for image lists. The
>   Image­List_Set­Overlay­Image function supports up to 15 image list
>   overlays per image list. (Hey, it used to be worse. The limit used to
>   be only 3!)
>
> Okay, but why only 15? Why not more?
>
> The overlay image is one of the pieces of information used when
>   drawing an image from an image list. The options are encoded in the
>   fStyle parameter, and when the bits were divided up for various
>   purposes, four bits were available to be used to specify the overlay
>   image. (You get 15 overlay images instead of 16 because you lose one
>   of the values in order to specify “no overlay.”)
>
> Okay, but the values in the fStyle parameter use only the bottom 16
>   bits. What about the upper 16 bits? There’s plenty of room there.
>
> The 16-bit limit was carried over from the 16-bit version of the
>   common controls (which still needed to be supported in Windows 95). Of
>   course, nowadays, nobody cares about the 16-bit version of the common
>   controls, so why not start using the upper bits?
>
> There’s an unsatisfying explanation: The code internally that manages
>   the fStyle still uses a WORD in some places, so all the code that
>   manages the fStyle would have to be revised. This occurs in multiple
>   modules across Windows, so a synchronized change would have to be made
>   across multiple components. This is a breaking change at the binary
>   level because the interfaces are no longer compatible. Breaking
>   changes are procedurally difficult to coordinate: The affected code
>   may not be visible to the shell team because they are sitting in a
>   far-away leaf branch that has not yet RI’d to the trunk. It might be
>   that expanding fStyle from a WORD to a DWORD has far-reaching
>   consequences for some component.

So Microsoft can't really fix it without breaking Explorer.

Open regedit, go to

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` and
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`

and count the number of items. Are you hitting the limit of 15?

If yes, then either uninstall or reconfigure applications that are shown here or remove the registry entries manually (backing them up of course).

Comment: I had both installed on my Windows7 - and probably **a lot** of stuff more - the win7 was running for ~3 years...

Comment: open regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`and count the number of items. Are you hitting the limit of 15?

Comment: 20 items.... it's gotten filled up with *Skydrive*. Arrgh!
(I uninstalled another program and now it works)

Comment: Remaining question though: Would it be safe to manually remove Registry entries in that "folder" ?

Comment: this i save, but make a backup of the key first and next disable entries you don't need. I also have the issue and removed some TSVN entries.

Comment: Can't blame the user ('you've installed too many'  ...) - maybe some apps are just greedy;  Dropbox takes 10, OneDrive takes 5, TortoiseSvn takes 9, leaving none for anyone else!

Comment: @EdRandall I don't blame anyone. windows has this ugly 15 overlay icon limit. so send feedback to MS. I annoy them for years, but if more users complain, they may fix it.

Comment: This [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091209-00/?p=15723/) by a Microsoft employee gives an explanation on why their stance might be that it's not the limit that is the problem, but the way overlays are (ab)used by third-party apps. As the post points out, they're not really suited to display properties, since only one overlay can be shown at a time. So if you use TortoiseSVN and Dropbox, and store a repository in your Dropbox folder, it already gets confusing. Of course, Microsoft is guilty of this abuse themselves, with the OneDrive client.

Comment: @DanielSaner there is a technical limit. See the newest blog from Raymond Chen

Answer (score 20):

you don't necessarily need to delete any keys, all you have to do is to rename these keys with a number in front of them in sequential order then restart the machine. The sequential numbers will make sure that your OS only counts the top 15.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: This is just a fine example of Windows in all it's insanity.

Comment: That is almost certain to confuse the relevant apps or their [un]installers ...

Comment: It doesn't really help. Skydrive for example is once per week or so renaming it's icons. I don't want to do this regularly.

Comment: The workaround I found (and one that has worked for me for several years) is to add *copies* of the overlays I want to show up with names that are before all the others... e.g. `___CRD3333DropboxExt1`.  It's a very ugly hack, but does make the overlays stable.

Comment: By exporting the registry settings I discovered that the greedy Dropbox and OneDrive  precede their key names with spaces (which do not show up in RegEdit and will win in an ASCII sort) - so you need to be quite crafty with your key name prefixes '<sp><sp><sp>011keyname'

Comment: After the registry export, fix-up the file, import again, a logout/login was sufficient to restore the overlays, no need to reboot (Win10)