# Disable OneDrive Status column in explorer windows

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Looking for help on how you can permanently remove the OneDrive Status column in Windows 10.  If you right-click and remove the column, then navigate back to the same folder, it will re-appear.

[Screenshot of Status column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc7dt.png)

I've checked other threads on this issue here:

[How to remove OneDrive icon overlay checkmarks in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/969655/how-to-remove-onedrive-icon-overlay-checkmarks-in-windows-10)
Is old and no longer works.

[Which OneDrive icon/status is for which Icon Overlay Identifier name?](https://superuser.com/questions/1037648/which-onedrive-icon-status-is-for-which-icon-overlay-identifier-name)
Is old and no longer works.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use OneDrive, it can be removed from Explorer with the following Registry script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000
```

To restore it, change the values `00000000` to `00000001`

Comment: I use OneDrive.