# TortoiseSVN shell overlays only showing for medium and large icons in explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10, tortoise-svn

I have one computer where the TortoiseSVN shell icon overlays only display for medium and large icons in the Explorer on Windows 10. If I change to small icons or detailed view they disappear in the main window. The strange part is that the icons appear on in the favorites on the left hand side.

I have updated the registry to prefix the TortoiseSVN icons with two spaces in:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
```

I have cleared the cache and restarted.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: try 1.9.1 which renames the overlay icons on its own: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.9.1/

Comment: Thanks user3163, that was the issue. [I posted your answer on Stackoverflow.com, where a number of other possible solutions are posted too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964627/tortoisesvn-icons-overlay-not-showing-after-updating-to-windows-10/38076966)

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/542116/why-are-icon-overlays-from-3rdparty-apps-not-showing-up-in-the-win8-explorer/637070

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out to be different DPI-scaling on the primary and secondary monitor. When the secondary monitor was set to 125% (same as the primary monitor) the icons appeared again.

Answer (score 0):

[TortoiseSVN 1.9.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.9.1/) will work around the issue by renaming the Overlay Icons (starting with 2 spaces) to [make sure they are loaded before the OneDrive icons.](http://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/code/26717/)